# How to access the table of one database from other database , both the databases are on same server in sqlserver

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, ssms

i have two database residing on same server , say I have db1 and db2 , now i want to access some tables from db1 from db2 , how can I do this in Sql Server-12?

Comment: Which Azure database do you use? Azure sql database or managed insatance? If it's Azure SQL single database, you can use elastic query to achieve that. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview

Comment: Hello @Vinod Kumar, welcome to stack overflow! If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure SQL database(single database), [USE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not supported. We can use Elastic query to achieve across database query.

Ref: [Azure SQL Database elastic query overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview):

- The elastic query feature (in preview) enables you to run a
  Transact-SQL query that spans multiple databases in Azure SQL
  Database. It allows you to perform cross-database queries to access
  remote tables, and to connect Microsoft and third-party tools (Excel,
  Power BI, Tableau, etc.) to query across data tiers with multiple
  databases. Using this feature, you can scale out queries to large
  data tiers and visualize the results in business intelligence (BI)
  reports.

If you're using Azure SQL managed instance, it's same with on-premise SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i am using Azure SQL Database and with help of Elastic query i am able to access the cross database tables.

Comment: @VinodKumar You're welcome! can you please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

for example you want to access to ***table[A]*** > ***schema[dbo]*** > ***database[C]***

> Assume current user has access to both database

```
SELECT * FROM [C].[dbo].[A]
```

Join ***[A] table*** from ***[schema_1] schema*** from  ***[db_1] Database*** and ***[B] table*** from ***[schema_2] schema*** from ***[db_2] Database*** from different database on same server

> When use db_1

```
USE [db_1]
SELECT * FROM [schema_1].[A] AS [db_1_A] INNER JOIN [db_2].[schema_2].[B] AS [db_2_B] ON [db_1_A].[field_1]=[db_2_B].[field_1]
```

> When use db_2

```
USE [db_2]
SELECT * FROM [db_1].[schema_1].[A] AS [db_1_A] INNER JOIN [schema_2].[B] AS [db_2_B] ON [db_1_A].[field_1]=[db_2_B].[field_1]
```